# inheriting a read-only property

Tags: c#, .net

In Microsoft documentation, the declaration for the read-only property Controls of the Control class is as so:

```
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public Control.ControlCollection Controls { get; }
```

I am inheriting this property. And hiding it:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
[ComVisible(false)]
public new Control.ControlCollection Controls { get; }
```

but this doesn't compile? *Error: ‘UserControl1.Controls.get’ must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.*

So I change it:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
[ComVisible(false)]
public new Control.ControlCollection Controls { 
    get { return null; } }
```

Which does compile. But I need a bit of the properties functionality, and not to completely nullify it. (I must apologize to the early respondents to this post for my considerable edit here.) (Within 30 seconds!!)
I must change my script... so I try:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
[ComVisible(false)]
public new Control.ControlCollection Controls { get; private set; }
```

This too won't compile: *Error: The accessibility modifier of the 'UserControl1.Controls.set' accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer 'UserControl1.Controls'*

What's to be done about this?

Comment: When you use `new` you are not inheriting the property, you are hiding the parent's definition.

Comment: For the first part you are only getting the property so what will your get return ?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault ...edited that. Hiding. what i wanted was hiding. and so { get return null; } which works. but now it's a hopeless mess.

Comment: a hopeless mess, that really helps. maybe you want return base.Controls ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck that should do it. Thanks for restoring the order!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I suggest.

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
[ComVisible(false)]
public new Control.ControlCollection Controls { 
    get { return base.Controls; } }
```

Comment: Yes, specifically if he only wants to get and if he wants to set it than no meaning of readonly.... :)

Comment: Sure! besides I see the Controls property is actually written  public ControlCollection Controls { 
            get {
                ControlCollection controlsCollection = (ControlCollection)Properties.GetObject(PropControlsCollection);
  
                if (controlsCollection == null) {
                    controlsCollection = CreateControlsInstance();
                    Properties.SetObject(PropControlsCollection, controlsCollection);
                }
                return controlsCollection;
            }
        }